# Publish to flash player 9, Stage Video available if browser plugin 10.2 or greater?

Tags: flash, video, stage

I'm hoping someone can clear up some confusion. I have a flash video player and for widest compatibility I want to only target flash player version9. So in my embed code I will only be checking for flash player version 9 or greater.
However, if a user has version 10.2 or greater of the flash plugin installed, there is a new very powerful feature called Stage Video which will allow MUCH greater full screen and full browser video performance.

My question is, assuming a user has the 10.2 or greater plugin, will StageVideo be available under the above scenario (publish to FP9), or do I have to also publish targeting fp10??

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to me is making two different video player and a loader swf. Loader swf's purpose is getting FP version and loading efficient video player.
You can also build one video player but it is cleaner and better to do it separate.

example code to get version from this site -> http://www.mediacollege.com/adobe/flash/actionscript/3/player-version.html

```
var flashVersion:Object = new Object();// Object to hold the Flash version details

function getPlayerVersion() {
   var versionNumber:String = Capabilities.version;// Get the whole version string
   var versionArray:Array = versionNumber.split(",");// Split it up
   var length:Number = versionArray.length;
   var osPlusVersion:Array = versionArray[0].split(" ");// The main version contains the OS (e.g. WIN), so we split that off as well.
   // Populate the version object (the OS is a string, others are numbers):
   flashVersion["os"] = osPlusVersion[0];
   flashVersion["major"] = parseInt(osPlusVersion[1]);
   flashVersion["minor"] = parseInt(versionArray[1]);
   flashVersion["build"] = parseInt(versionArray[2]);
   // Test the output:
   trace(flashVersion["os"]);
   trace(flashVersion["major"]);
   trace(flashVersion["minor"]);
   trace(flashVersion["build"]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I disagree that making 2 versions is somehow 'cleaner'. Unless you are using some FP10 specific code within your flash player(like the vector construct) there is no reason really why you need to target FP10+. And AFAIK, as long as the plugin version is greater than or equal to your published version, it should play fine.

Comment: That is my way. You decide. If you make a video player that runs on every situation, file will be large.